# recursive function for subset sum problem with floating-point numbers

Tags: r, precision, subset-sum

I made a recursion function `f(s,x)` for the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is able to produce all unique combinations that sum up to the target sum 's' when picking elements from the set of values `x`.

For example, assuming `x <- c(2,4,8,10)`, and `s <- 10` denotes the target sum, with the function `f` below

```
f <- function(s, x, xhead = head(x,1), r = c()) {
  if (s == 0) {
    return(list(r))
  } else {
    x <- sort(x,decreasing = T)
    return(unlist(lapply(x[x<=min(xhead,s)], function(k) f(s-k, x[x<= s-k], min(k,head(x[x<=s-k],1)), c(r,k))),recursive = F)) 
  }
}
```

I can get all combinations for subset sum, i.e.,

```
> f(s,x)
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 8 2

[[3]]
[1] 4 4 2

[[4]]
[1] 4 2 2 2

[[5]]
[1] 2 2 2 2 2
```

The function above works well with integers for `x` and `s`. ***However***, when I scaled down both `x` and `s` by 10, i.e., floating-point numbers for `x` and `s`, then the output becomes the undesired ones:

```
> f(s/10,x/10)
[[1]]
[1] 1
```

but the desired output should be like

```
> Map(function(v) v/10, f(s,x))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 0.8 0.2

[[3]]
[1] 0.4 0.4 0.2

[[4]]
[1] 0.4 0.2 0.2 0.2

[[5]]
[1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
```

I suspect there must be some wring for my function `f` when dealing with floating-point numbers, but failed to fix it after several trials. Can anyone help me address this issue without big changes for the function `f`?

Appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `round` in your subtraction and set the decimal points

```
f <- function(s, x, xhead = head(x,1), r = c()) {
  if (s == 0) {
    return(list(r))
  } else {
    x <- sort(x,decreasing = T)
    return(unlist(lapply(x[x<=min(xhead,s)], function(k) f(round(s-k, 4), x[x<= round(s-k, 4)], min(k,head(x[x<= round(s-k, 4)],1)), c(r,k))),recursive = F)) 
  }
}

f(s/10,x/10)
```

Which returns the desired output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 0.8 0.2

[[3]]
[1] 0.4 0.4 0.2

[[4]]
[1] 0.4 0.2 0.2 0.2

[[5]]
[1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
```